# XCODE does not have iPad Pro 6th generation

Tags: ios, xcode

My Xcode doesn't have the simulator installed. When I go to windows=>devices and simulators to install it, I don't see iPad Pro 12.9 inch (6th generation) listed. How do I go install it the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

In Devices and Simulators, click Simulators. At the bottom left, click the Plus button (`+`). Look thru the Device Type pop-up menu until you find the iPad Pro 6th generate. Choose it.

[image]

If you don't see it, update your Xcode.